# How to differentiate sub classes in an ArrayList of super class

Tags: java, object, inheritance

I have 2 subclasses(MultiCard and BasicCard) and I want to call a method(addCurrency) belonging to MultiCard from the class Bank.
 The method is used to add more currency inside a MultiCard which has an ArrayList of currencies. However, because MultiCard is the sub-class of class Card, I can't access the MultiCard. All cards are stored in a `List<Card>cards`;

I do not want to use a casting based solution (checking with `instanceof` and then casting the `Card` instance to a `MultiCard`)
The Super Class:

```
public abstract class Card implements Comparable<Card>, Cloneable
{
protected String id;
protected String name;
protected List<Purchase> purchases;
static int counter = 1000;

public Card(String name)
{
    counter++;
    this.id = Integer.toString(counter);
    this.name = name;
    this.purchases = new ArrayList<Purchase>();
}
```

The method I want to use in class MultiCard extends Card

```
public class MultiCard extends Card implements Cloneable
{
protected static List<String> currencies;
protected double[] balance;
public static final int currencyCount = 5;
public MultiCard (String name)
{
    super (name);
    currencies = new ArrayList<String>();
    balance = new double[currencyCount];
    currencies.add ("AUD");
    for (int i = 0; i < balance.length; i++)
        balance[i] = 0;
}
public boolean addCurrency (String currency)
{
    if (currencies.size () == currencyCount ||containsCurrency (currency)) {
        return false;
    }
    currencies.add (currency);
    return true;
}
```

The method addCurrency() that I need to modify in class Bank

```
private static final String[] currencyLabel = { "AUD", "NZD", "USD", "CND", "YEN", "BPD" };
private static final double[] currencyRate = { 1.0, 1.2, 0.75, 0.85, 80, 0.7 };
private String adminUsername;
private String adminPassword;

Map<String, User> users = new HashMap<>();// username

public Bank(String admName, String admPassword){
    this.adminUsername  = admName;
    this.adminPassword = admPassword;
public boolean addCurrency(String cardID, String username, String password, String currency) { ...
}
```

The method addCurrency is used to add a currency inside a List which is in MultiCard. It calls the method in the MultiCard

This is what I tried:

```
public boolean addCurrency(String cardID, String username, String password, String currency)
{
   User user = users.get(username);
   user.getACard(cardID, username, password); // here is my problem - a Card instance is returned, which must be cast to a MultiCard

}
```

Comment: Please share complete code. Your question is very confusing

Comment: Not able to understand what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: hello i have editted my question

Comment: @GlenioAlsinTan You have edited the question, yes. But you haven't made it any clearer. What **is** your question? Assume we know nothing about your code (because we don't) or what you're trying to do (because we don't). :)

Comment: @GlenioAlsinTan : I read your question carefully and edited it in order to reflect what I believe your intentions are. I also changed all you DS declarations to declare DS interfaces (List,Map) instead of DS implementations (ArrayList,HashMap). The DS interfaces should be the ones being used - you should never be bound to a specific implementation, but rather use an API.

Comment: Declare the method in the base class, and override it in the SimpleCard class to always return false (since that's apparently the way you chose to signal that the operation did nothing). You can also make it return false in the base class directly.

Comment: @RannLifshitz, pardon my ignorance, but what is _DS_ ?

Comment: @Abra Data Structure I guess.

Comment: On further inspection of the provided code: you have declared the currencies `List` to be static, and then you modify it using a method call. This is a bad practice - you should modify a static attribute using a static method since this attribute is a class attribute, not an instance attribute. If this is the case, IMHO the design of the code should be changed - if you want to add currencies you should access the `MultiCard` class, and not a specific instance of `Card`.

Comment: Thankyou for the inspection @RannLifshitz. I have wrote a further question in the answer comment.

Answer (score 2):

Since the question is a bit confusing, I assume that when you are calling `user.getACard(cardID, username, password)` method, you are getting an object of `Card` . Ideal fix would be that To invoke `addCurency()` method, 
You can add an abstract method `public boolean addCurrency (String currency)` in the Card class (if at all you are allowed to modify the Card class). 
Otherwise you will have to cast the `Card` Object to `MultiCard` Object.

Comment: Thankyou for understanding, is the casting is down casting? Do you know which is the best way to clone Card, because it is an abstract object so i used an abstract clone() and create clone() to the subclasses, however i got null. *sorry my question is confusing english is not my first language.

Comment: The Casting would not be a down Casting.  ```user.getACard(...)``` is always  going to return a concrete object ( ie that of MultiCard) . But since the return type of this method is of type Card, the Concrete Multicard Object Is always going to be referenced by a  Card Reference. when you are casting here, you are just making the reference of the concrete object more specific to Multicard.